# For $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, $\Bbb E(S_n/n)^2\to\mu^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of iids such that $\Bbb E(X_i) =\mu$ and $Var(X_i)<\infty$ for each $i$. Then by SLLN, if $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then $S_n/n\to\mu$ a.s. so that $(S_n/n)^2\to\mu^2$ a.s. I want to put $\Bbb E$ on both sides so that $\Bbb E(S_n/n)^2\to\mu^2$. Is there a way to justify putting $\Bbb E$ on both sides?

Comment: Expectations are not random variables, so it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Oh right convergence in probability doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(S_n/n)^2 = E(\sum_i\sum_jX_iX_j)/n^2 = [nE X_i^2 + n(n-1)\mu^2]/n^2\to \mu^2$ because $E X_i^2 <\infty$.

Comment: Ah, they're iid so $\Bbb EX_i^2$ are all the same, in particular independent of $n$!